# PostgreSQL extension set-up

Tags: php, xampp, installation, ini, php-pgsql

I'm trying to set-up a connecting with PHP to a PostgreSQL database.

I uncommented the following in PHP.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
```

If I go to XAMPP => Services, I see postgresql-64-9.3 as one of them. I try to launch it, but it doesn't work.

-

Using the following:

```
echo extension_loaded('pgsql') ? 'yes':'no';
```

Returns 'no'.

-

Using the a pg_connect() results in the following:
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function pg_connect() in ..

Answer (score 0):

Also uncommnet extension=php_pgsql.dll.And make sure php_pgsql.dll,php_pdo_pgsql.dll and libpq.dll are added in the bin folder where Postgresql is installed.(c/program files/PostgreSQL/bin)